# My code works when i f8 through it and doesnt when i f5

Tags: excel, vba, png

My code below works to move a grouped chart picture with a heading into a png file.  For some reason it sometimes randomly works when I f8, sometimes however it creates a blank png file through f8.  If I f5 through it is either always blank.png or says permission denied.

Can you help?

```
Sub ExportChart()
    Dim chrtobj As ChartObject
    Dim chtobj As ChartObject
    Dim myfilename As String

    Dim myChart As Picture
    Dim myshape As Variant
    Dim TF As Variant

    Sheets("SUMMARY INFOGRAPHIC").Activate

    TF = Cells(1, 5).Value


    Set myshape = Sheet31.Shapes("group 17")

    myshape.CopyPicture

'Create a new chartobject with the same dimensions as the source shape
 Set chtobj = Sheet31.ChartObjects.Add(myshape.Left, myshape.Top, myshape.Width, myshape.Height)

'Paste the object from the clipboard to the new chart
chtobj.Chart.Paste



    myfilename = TF & ".png"


    On Error Resume Next
    Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myfilename
    On Error GoTo 0

'chtObj.Chart.Export Filename:=fullpathandfilename, Filtername:="PNG"

chtobj.Chart.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myfilename, FilterName:="PNG"

'Then delete the chart and clean up objects.
chtobj.Delete
Set chtobj = Nothing


    MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```

Comment: It is all very fuzzy. Are you using `Option Explicit`? Where is `chtObj` declared? The bug may be at `chtObj.Chart.Paste` as `.Paste` method applies to a `Chart` object so it should rather be a `chtObj.Paste`. And please try to tidy the code in your question because it is difficult to undestand in this format.

Comment: HI Sorry I will amend my code now, not used to posting on here.  I tried the .paste change and got a not supported error.  I'M not a great vba coder so any help appreciated

Comment: I didn't use option explicit so I did and dimmed he variables that needed dimming.